# Why does Stack Overflow have two verified profiles on StackShare.io?

Tags: discussion

Just wondering why Stack Overflow has two verified profiles on [StackShare.io](https://stackshare.io/) with differing Tool Stacks?

The two profiles are;

- https://stackshare.io/stack-overflow/stack-overflow
- https://stackshare.io/stack-exchange/stack-overflow

It looks as though there is some confusion around how StackShare build these profiles or has Stack Overflow been registered twice against two different entities?

Comment: Shame we can't vote to close one profile as duplicate of the other...

Comment: Relevant/related comment from SE staff: [*We are not affiliated with StackShare at all*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337211/what-is-stackshare-actually#comment1119901_337211)

Comment: Because two different developers at the company opened profiles at different times, when the company name used publicly was different, probably. That difference also explains the difference in stacks.